# Cocos2d, how to do a certain touch method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I have this sprite that I want to touch and as soon as I am no longer touching it I want to call a method nslog "not touching". Right now the way I have the code set up it only calls method nslog "not touching" when I tap something else.I want to call method nslog "touching" when an object is getting touch ,but as soon as I touch something else or lift my finger it will call nslog "not touching". Any suggestions? 
Thank you for your time.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
NSSet *allTouches = [event allTouches];
UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
CGPoint location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:location];
 int arraysize = [brain count];
for (int i = 0; i < arraysize; i++) {
if (CGRectContainsPoint( [[brain objectAtIndex:0]  boundingBox], location)) {
        NSLog(@"touched");
        }else {

NSLog(@"not touched");
   }}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to register your touch handler as targeted touch delegate. It will allow you to swallow this touch.

You should process all delegate methods. I mean, `touchBegan:withEvent:`, `touchMoved:withEvent:`,  `touchEnded:withEVent:`. So, just store touch when it is began if it's position is inside sprite's rect. Then just in `touchMoved:withEvent:` and `touchEnded:withEvent:` process stored touch position to determine if touch had leaved sprite's rect.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to define `ccTouchesEnded`.